# how to pass url in dialog box

Tags: javascript, dojo

how to pass any jsp url in dialogbox of dijit

Comment: your question could stand to have more detail in it.

Answer (score 0):

To load a Dialog from a URL:

```
<div dojoType=dijit.Dialog href=...></div>
```